# How can a pivot table filter destroy dynamic named ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

**Problem is sloved, answer is below**

I have a code that has been working great the past months.
During the night between yesterday and today while nobody as using the computer ( only a automatic VBA code running) it stopped working.

In short the automatic VBA code updates a table on sheet 1, a pivot table on sheet 2 uses the first four charaters of the time and the value at that time.
Example (time is 10:15) `time = 10:1, value = 5555`. The reason for the truncing of the last minute is to get a "rounded number", when this scales to months of data it's better to have 10:1 than 10:15, 10:16 and 10:17 and so on.

After the data is on sheet 2, a named range is used to get the interesting part of the table (two rows above first value > 0 to end of table) usually that means row 35~40 and end at row 148-ish.

```
 =OFFSET(Blad2!$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$148<>0,0)-3,0,MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$148="",0)-MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$148<>0,0)+2,1)
```

This named range is used in a chart.

The VBA that by some reason starting yesterday destroys this is:

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").Calculate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields("Datum").ClearAllFilters
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").PivotTables("Pivottabell1").PivotFields("Veckodag").ClearAllFilters
```

The Pivot table looks like this:
[image]

What I'm doing is changing the filter of the table from as the picture shows Thursdays to Fridays.
And to do that I need to reset the filters first then loop and unset all but Friday.
But as soon as the filter is reset the dynamic ranges stops working.
What can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was typing this question I found the problem.
I was literally typing the second last line *But as soon as the*, and that is when I figured it out.

I believe this can be a problem for others too so that is why I keep the question.

The problem is the pivot table grew downwards.
I thought I had all the "rounded times" in my table but it seems one was missing and that caused it to expand past where the dynamic range was trying to find the end of the table.
By just adding two rows to the range (148 => 150) it all worked fine again.

```
=OFFSET(Blad2!$B$5,MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$150<>0,0)-3,0,MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$150="",0)-MATCH(TRUE,Blad2!$B$5:$B$150<>0,0)+2,1)
```

I have now double checked that all "rounded times" are in the table so it can't grow again.

Yes, I should buy a rubber duck...